# Duplicates removal from different excel files at a time

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have 5 folders and each folder consists of around 20 excel sheets. 
And these excel sheets contain duplicates within it. It is becoming very hectic to open every file and remove duplicates.

Is there anyother way to remove duplicates from all these files at once ?

All the files contain different set of duplicates and no common columns will be present.

Answer (score 0):

XD I'm really understanding your situation but I think that the solution will be one of two :) :

1-make a program with any programming language you can use and try to load the files one by one to do what you want

2-(the easiest one)Try to find a good converter to convert all your files to SQL tables then come here to this site and ask how to delete duplicated rows from different SQL tables after doing that reconvert the SQL tables to EXCEL files again and it will be done (y) ;)

Comment: Well I cannot use any converters as it is a part of my office work. Should look for few more thoughts and suggestions. Thank you.